# z-index lost when parent has css animation

Tags: css, z-index, css-animations

I have a child elements which I have stacked behind the parent using a z-index. But, once I add an animation to the parent, the z-index is not honoured.

This happens on both Firefox and Chrome, I have not tested on IE.

I assume this is a bug rather than behaviour expected of CSS, but does anyone have a workaround?

http://codepen.io/MattyBalaam/pen/Gakmr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#effects)

> Any computed value other than none for the transform results in the
>   creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object
>   acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

I think that is the cause of your problem, once the parent animates, the child becomes stacked

You may try to add a wrapping element, and animate it, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Mc3y/

```
<span class="wrap animated">
    <span class="overlay">parent animated
        <span class="below">b</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you that fixes the issue. Do you think the W3C expect the current behaviour to produce this result though?

Comment: yes, I don't think they're going to fix that, because according to then, it's not broken